# MariaDB InnoDB does not rollback on timeout

Tags: mysql, mariadb, transaction, rollback

I have the ff. sample queries in this sequence:

1. START TRANSACTION
2. UPDATE
3. INSERT
4. COMMIT

Query #2 is timing out but I noticed that query #3 is not rolled back.

I am also trying to manually rollback by verifying (querying the table) if the updates went through before I commit. But when I do that, I get an explicit: `General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away` error.

My questions:

1. I have `innodb_rollback_on_timeout` set to `ON`, isn't query #3 supposed to be rolled back?
2. Since I can't even manually roll back, what options do I have?

Note: This is on mariadb-10.4.17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the client?  Does it have "auto reconnect" turned on?  Turn it off.

What I think is happening:

1. The `UPDATE` croaks (in any way) and gets rolled back.
2. The connection is reestablished, perhaps with `autocommit`.
3. The `INSERT` runs successfully and autocommits.
4. The `COMMIT` is silently ignored.

Put error checks after *every* SQL statement.

Comment: Client is PHP PDO. I trace the code to find if any auto-reconnection is going on, what I found instead was `UPDATE` and `INSERT` was coming from different connections. While I may never find why `UPDATE` is timing out, I think I found the bigger issue --using transaction with different connections.